# Need help designing application with UIPageControl and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone

I have looked at the PageControl example from Apple and have an architectural requirement difference.  In the example the scroll view and page control objects are at the app delegate level.  This means the scroll view and page control appears on every view of the application.

However, I have a "settings" view toggled from an info button (for now) that should not have these controls displayed.  Therefore, I need to move my scroll view, page control, and view controllers objects down a layer and I'm struggling with how to best do this.

For example, the primary application view consists of metals (periodic elements).  From this view I need a scroll view, page control, and info button on every view descending from here.  Each metal will have it's own subclass where different images, calculations, etc will be displayed but I believe I need each of these subclassed elements to share the same scroll view, page control, and viewControllers array, right?  Do I need a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is kind of like how the native Weather application works.  Each time you swipe, the info light is rendered as part of the page you are viewing.  However, no matter what info light you tap, when it flips over you still get the same settings.  Obviously this is how Apple thinks the UI should work because they did it that way.  There is no reason you can't do the same.

In this situation, you don't need to create a singleton, you can use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` as your singleton to get to your custom application delegate via the `delegate` property.

Comment: Yes I need to make my app function exactly like the weather app.  My problem is I don't have the source code for Weather to look at as an example.  The PageControl source examples have the page control and scroll view in the app delegate.  I don't believe this would be the case for the weather app because when you flip to the settings page you no longer see the page control and can no longer scroll.

Comment: At that point what you can do is simply remove the ScrollView from it's superview, and add in your settings during the swap

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Crème](http://cremeapp.com) where I do exactly what you describe. The main view is scrollview+pagecontrol. Upon triggering the app into settings mode, the settings panel comes up that does not have a page control.

The solution is simply that you have a simple top-level UIViewController, and you make both the scrollview and pageview children of that viewcontroller. And for settings, you animate the modal settings dialog with a flip animation into the top-level UIViewController.